# C# timers.timer is not working correctly. it seems to be overlapping

Tags: c#, timer, overlap

Thanks for your attention.

Here's what my code does:

A method(Using C# WinForm, System.timers.timer) that checks the variables every second, leaves a log, and moves on to the next function if the condition is met.

After working for quite long time(more than 2 weeks), the following symptoms occurred :

overlapping logs left by the timer.

The period of the timer is 1 second, and the operation of the timer is not considered heavy.

here is example of the logs

```
[14:06:05]A
[14:06:05]B
[14:06:05]B
[14:06:05]B
[14:06:05]B
[14:06:05]B
... (20 times/sec)
```

I just couldn't figure out why.
I tried running several PGMs simultaneously and applied several timers asynchronously, but the symptoms did not appear.

Ask for advice from teachers. I would like to refer to it for problem solving and study.
Detailed code is below.

This is how I initialized it.

```
 private static System.Timers.Timer TestEndDetection_Timer_;


 private void SetUp_TestEndDetection_Timer_()
        {

            TestEndDetection_Timer_ = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

            TestEndDetection_Timer_.Elapsed += TestEndDetection_Timer_Event;
            TestEndDetection_Timer_.AutoReset = true;
            TestEndDetection_Timer_.Enabled = true;
        }
```

I use that 'SetUp_TestEndDetection_Timer_()' only once when PGM start (Form_load())

here is code of TestEndDetection_Timer_Event()

```
 private void TestEndDetection_Timer_Event(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            defrostCount++;
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            
                        
            if (NowTesting && AutoDefrost && checkBox2.Checked)
            {
               
                TestEndDetectionDealyTimer++;
                
                if (TestEndDetectionDealyTimer > 180)
                {
                    bool Fix1End = false;
                    bool Fix2End = false;
                    bool Fix3End = false;
                    bool Fix4End = false;
                    bool Fix5End = false;
                    bool Fix6End = false;

                    bool Fix1Done = false;
                    bool Fix2Done = false;
                    bool Fix3Done = false;
                    bool Fix4Done = false;
                    bool Fix5Done = false;
                    bool Fix6Done = false;

                    bool Fix1Power = false;
                    bool Fix2Power = false;
                    bool Fix3Power = false;
                    bool Fix4Power = false;
                    bool Fix5Power = false;
                    bool Fix6Power = false;

                    Fix1Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix1\hdiag.log");
                    Fix2Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix2\hdiag.log");
                    Fix3Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix3\hdiag.log");
                    Fix4Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix4\hdiag.log");
                    Fix5Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix5\hdiag.log");
                    Fix6Done = File.Exists(@"Z:\result\fix6\hdiag.log");

                    defrostlogger("TESTDONE: "+Convert.ToInt32(Fix1Done) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix2Done) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix3Done) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix4Done) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix5Done) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix6Done));

                    Fix1Power = m_ucFixInfo[1].PowerStat;
                    Fix2Power = m_ucFixInfo[2].PowerStat;
                    Fix3Power = m_ucFixInfo[3].PowerStat;
                    Fix4Power = m_ucFixInfo[4].PowerStat;
                    Fix5Power = m_ucFixInfo[5].PowerStat;
                    Fix6Power = m_ucFixInfo[6].PowerStat;
                   
                    defrostlogger("POWER: "+Convert.ToInt32(Fix1Power) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix2Power) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix3Power) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix4Power) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix5Power) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(Fix6Power));
                    
                    
                    if (Fix1Done || !Fix1Power) { Fix1End = true; } else { Fix1End = false; }
                    if (Fix2Done || !Fix2Power) { Fix2End = true; } else { Fix2End = false; }
                    if (Fix3Done || !Fix3Power) { Fix3End = true; } else { Fix3End = false; }
                    if (Fix4Done || !Fix4Power) { Fix4End = true; } else { Fix4End = false; }
                    if (Fix5Done || !Fix5Power) { Fix5End = true; } else { Fix5End = false; }
                    if (Fix6Done || !Fix6Power) { Fix6End = true; } else { Fix6End = false; }
                                       
                    if (Fix1End && Fix2End && Fix3End && Fix4End && Fix5End && Fix6End && AutoDefrostRunStat && TestEndCount < 20)
                    {
                        TestEndCount++;
                    }
                                        
                    if (TestEndCount > 10)
                    {
                        

                        if (button13.Text == "Door Open" && DefrostAvailable)
                        {
                            defrostlogger("A");
                            RunDefrost();
                            AutoDefrostRunStat = false;
                            NowTesting = false;
                            TestEndCount = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            defrostlogger("B");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (defrostCount % 10 == 9&&NowTesting)
                {
                    Load_SV_txt();
                    defrostCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

defrostlogger is :

```
private void defrostlogger(string msg)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file_ = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\Logs\DefrostLog_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd") + ".txt", true))
            {
                file_.WriteLine("[" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "]" + msg);
            }
        }
```

1. I did a PGM test in the same environment as when the log was created: no symptoms.
2. I tried running several PGMs simultaneously : no symptoms.
3. I Applied several same timers asynchronously : log function was not worked.
4. Exploring issues related to c# timers on stackoverflow: There are no similar symptoms.

Comment: Any code that contains this `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` is pretty much bad code by definition, so you should address that for a start.

Comment: The `Elapsed` event is raised on a `ThreadPool` thread. I haven't checked to confirm but I would assume that that means that multiple event handlers can be executing simultaneously on different threads. That would happen if any one event handler took longer to execute than the value of `Interval`.

Comment: As a general advice, don't repeat yourself and create unit tests with assertions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks to your advice. I recognized that the syntax you mentioned is fundamentally bad. I'll try to figure out what causes the action not to finish within the interval.

Comment: @aybe Thank you. I'll focus on the basics.